# Android dependency included multiple times, causes app to reach dex limit

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

I have an android app structured like this:

main-app/

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':lib-A')
    compile project(':lib-B')
}
```

lib-A/

```
dependencies {
    compile 'Large3PLib'
    compile 'Other-libs'
}
```

lib-B/

```
dependencies {
    compile 'Large3PLib'
}
```

When I compile I am reaching the multi-dex limit, and I see that main-app, lib-A, and lib-B all have very large dex counts due to them all including 'Large3PLib'.  Is there a way I can tell gradle to only include 'Large3PLib' once in order to shrink my dex count?

Notes:

- I have proguard enabled
- I've tried combining the code in main-app, lib-A, and lib-B into one large module.  This puts me back under the multidex limit, but I don't like this solution as now my code is no longer organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit `lib-A` and `lib-B` to mark the dependency as 'provided':

```
provided 'Large3PLib'
```

This means that it will not be included in the resulting jar or aar. But then you will have to add it to the root project:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'Large3PLib'
    compile project(':lib-A')
    compile project(':lib-B')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, one follow up question though:  One of my libraries uses resources (strings, themes, etc.) from 'Large3PLib'.  When I switch from `compile` to `provided` it cannot find the resources.  Does `provided' not include resources?

Comment: provided includes it when building, but not when packaging, so anything which comes from Large3PLib will not be added. That's why you have to include it again on the root level.